# JOOQ error of "Cannot connect to database using JDBC URL"

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, gradle, jooq

I am setting up a Kotlin/Gradle/Spring/JOOQ based application. When I try and run my code (there are no other files but the generic `BackendApplication.kts`, I get an error

Here is my `buidl.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.22"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "9.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq:3.19.3")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.1")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jooq {
   configurations {
      create("main") {
    generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(true)
    jooqConfiguration.apply {
       logging = Logging.WARN
       jdbc.apply {
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        url = "censored"
            user = "censored"
        password = "censored"
        properties.add(Property().apply {
           key = "ssl"
           value = "true"
        })
       }
       generator.apply {
        name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
        database.apply {
           name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
           inputSchema = "public"
           forcedTypes.addAll(listOf(
            ForcedType().apply {
               name = "varchar"
               includeExpression = ".*"
               includeTypes = "JSONB?"
            },
            ForcedType().apply {
               name = "varchar"
               includeExpression = ".*"
               includeTypes = "INET"
            }
           ))
            }
        generate.apply {
           isDeprecated = false
           isRecords = true
           isImmutablePojos = true
           isFluentSetters = true
        }
        target.apply {
           packageName = "com.example.Server.domain"
           directory = "build/generated-src/jooq/main"
            }
        strategy.name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"
         }
      }
      }
   }
}
```

When I try and run `BackendApplication.kts`, which is a basic starter application file that only calls `runApplication<BackendApplication>(*args)`, I get the following error

```
17:30:21 SEVERE Error in file: /Users/myName/Desktop/name/Code/Backend/build/tmp/generateJooq/config.xml. Error : Cannot connect to database using JDBC URL: CENSORED_URL Please review your JDBC configuration in the code generator configuration.
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot connect to database using JDBC URL: CENSORED_URL. Please review your JDBC configuration in the code generator configuration.
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:366)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:246)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:241)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:213)
```

Note that `CENSORED_URL` is my URL.

Am I missing something here? Clearly there is an issue when I setup the connection from JOOQ to my database, but I don't see what I did wrong. I can see my `User` database table in Postgres in PgAdmin. The credentials I input into JOOQ are exactly what I used to login with PgAdmin. Has anyone got this error before?

Comment: Make sure you have the Postgres JDBC driver JAR in your dependencies and check the URL to ensure that it follows the correct format.  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at jOOQ code, the only reason why this can happen is when `Driver.connect()` returns `null`:

```java
Connection c = driver.newInstance().connect(defaultString(j.getUrl()), properties);

if (c == null)
    throw new SQLException("Cannot connect to database using JDBC URL: " + j.getUrl() + ". Please review your JDBC configuration in the code generator configuration.");
```

And looking at pgjdbc code, the only reason why `Driver.connect()` can return `null` is when it thinks it's not the appropriate driver for a given URL:

```java
if (!url.startsWith("jdbc:postgresql:")) {
  return null;
}
```

That's also [what the JDBC spec mandates](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#connect(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)):

> The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kindof driver to connect to the given URL

So, your redacted JDBC URL must be wrong.